# How to create embedded mongodb database in quarkus?

Tags: mongodb, quarkus

I've been trying to create an embedded Mongodb database for the test, so far I wasn't able to make it work.

I've looked at https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/tree/main/test-framework/mongodb

I've also read this https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource but it doesn't seem updated

---

EDIT1:

**application.properties** (in my test package)

```
quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=${MONGO_URI:mongodb://localhost:19345/db-test}`
```

When I run my test I get the following error: `Cluster description not yet available. Waiting for 30000 ms before timing out` and then `Timed out after 30000 ms while waiting to connect. Client view of cluster state is {type=UNKNOWN, servers=[{address=localhost:19345, type=UNKNOWN, state=CONNECTING, exception={com.mongodb.MongoSocketOpenException: Exception opening socket}, caused by {java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)}}]`

---

EDIT2:

**application.properties**

```
%prod.quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=...
%prod.quarkus.mongodb.database=prod-db
```

**test**

```
@QuarkusTest
@TestMethodOrder(MethodOrderer.OrderAnnotation::class)
class ControllerTest {
    @Inject lateinit var accountRepository: MockAccountRepository

    @Test
    @Order(1)
    fun `badRequest`() {
        given()
            .`when`().get(endPoint)
            .then()
            .assertThat().statusCode(HttpResponseStatus.BAD_REQUEST.code())
    }
}
```

**MockAccount**

```kotlin
@Mock
@ApplicationScoped
class MockAccountRepository(mongoClient: MongoClient) {

    private val collection = mongoClient.getDatabase("db-test")
        .getCollection("account", MockAccount::class.java)

    ....
}
```

Comment: What version of quarkus are you using?

Comment: I'm using quarkus 2.1.2.Final

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, Quarkus 2.0+ version come with devServices support, which will start automatically a mongo database or other resources required to run your container, which are currently supported for the dev services module.
Here you can see information about this feature https://quarkus.io/guides/mongodb#dev-services This mongo database will available also for unit testing.

While using the devServices its important to do not override or define the configuration property `quarkus.mongodb.connection-string` for the dev or test profile if order to let quarkus handle the connection by itself.

---

If you want to start a different mongodb or just not use this feature you can create a new QuarkusTestResource where you can start whatever required dependency and manage its lifecycle. Here you have an example in kotlin https://github.com/javiertoja/stackoverflow/tree/main/kotlin-integration-tests-mongo .

As summary you have to create a class that implements the interface `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` like for example:

```
class MockMongoDatabase : QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private val mongoDBContainer = MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:4.0.10"))

    override fun start(): MutableMap<String, String> {
        println("STARTING MONGO ")
        mongoDBContainer.start()

        return mutableMapOf(Pair("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string",mongoDBContainer.replicaSetUrl))
    }

    override fun stop() {
        println("STOPPING MONGO")
        mongoDBContainer.stop()
    }
}
```

After that you will have to annotate the Test classes that require this resource to operate with the annotation `@QuarkusTestResource(MockMongoDatabase::class)`. This will instruct quarkus to startup this resource before the tests and shutdown it after finalizing.

---

If you want you can initialize your test resource with data in your test cases using the normal MongodbClient or whithin the QuarkusTestResourceLifecycle class which implements the resource.

Beware of mixing both because by default quarkus will try to use the devservices support if you don't disable it or you don't configure the connection properties.

Comment: I've read about the dev-service and that's what I'm using but it's not working properly. I've updated my post for better readability

Comment: Ahh oki, you don't need to provide this property, If you rely on devServices you should not provide this configuration. If you check the doc I post it says this "What that means practically, is that if you have not configured quarkus.mongodb.connection-string Quarkus will automatically start a MongoDB container when running tests or dev-mode, and automatically configure the connection."

Comment: I just commented the `quarkus.mongodb.connection-string` and run it again but same error, this time the port is the default one (27017)

Comment: Have you defined this property also in the application properties file which is present in the non-test resource folder ?

Comment: Yes, I'm using it to run my server and specify the database, port, username, password and such

Comment: This is fully correct. The dev services feature are active while quarkus is running with the profile "dev" or "test" which happens when you are in developming mode (quarkus:dev) or testing. If you put this configuration property then quarkus is not starting a new mongodb container for you because ir interprets that you are going to use an external database.

Comment: Do you want to use the devServices or do you prefer to use an external database that you can control (in docker or outside) ?

Comment: I want to create an embedded mongodb for my testing purpose/dev but use an external database when in prod for my prod parameter I use: `%prod.quarkus.mongodb.connection-string=...`

Comment: This is easy, you can define your production configuration with %prod.quarkus.mongodb.connection-string, by using %prod, you are telling quarkus that this configuration is for production only. It is also possible to override configuration with environmental variable at runtime https://quarkus.io/guides/config-reference

Comment: It is still not working, I've removed everything as it is said for devService. I've added more details in my original post (EDIT 2)

Comment: Ok, try the code in the repo of my response, with that code i setup a mongodb and query it. also disable the mongo devServices in your testing application properties

Answer (score 0):

you can use test containers to have MongoDB running "embedded".

Annotate your tests with `@QuarkusTestResource(MongoDBLifecycleManager.class)`.

And here we have the implementation of `MongoDBLifecycleManager`:

```
public class MongoDBLifecycleManager implements QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {

    private MongoDBContainer mongoDBContainer = new MongoDBContainer(DockerImageName.parse("mongo:5.0.10"));

    @Override
    public Map<String, String> start() {
        mongoDBContainer.start();

        return Map.of(
                "quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", mongoDBContainer.getConnectionString(),
                "quarkus.mongodb.database", "testDB");
    }

    @Override
    public void stop() {
        mongoDBContainer.stop();
    }
}
```

It is important to notice that your tests will ignore what you defined in the `application.properties` as MongoDB connection parameters, and use what the method `start` returns:

```
Map.of("quarkus.mongodb.connection-string", mongoDBContainer.getConnectionString(),
       "quarkus.mongodb.database", "testDB");
```

You can have other MongoDB instances running in your local machine, with test containers you will run it in a random port.

In your `pom.xml` you will need some like:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>testcontainers</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit-jupiter</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.testcontainers</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongodb</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
```

Basically during your test phase, it will download all dependencies, create a MongoDB container in a random port, execute all your tests, shutdown and cleanup.